# adding jpanels over split pane in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jsplitpane

I am trying to add three panels on a single JFrame form. if i am only adding three panels they are being displayed but if i add the panel on split pane nothing is being displayed 
suggest the error in following code

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 class paneltest extends JFrame{
 paneltest()
 {
   Container cp=this.getContentPane();
   cp.setLayout(null);
   panel1 p1= new panel1();
   panel2 p2= new panel2();
   panel3 p3= new panel3();
   cp.add(p1);
   cp.add(p2);
   cp.add(p3);
   Dimension screenSize=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

   p1.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width/3,screenSize.height);
   p2.setBounds(screenSize.width/3,0,screenSize.width/3,screenSize.height);
   p3.setBounds(2*(screenSize.width/3),0,screenSize.width/3,screenSize.height); 

   try{

       JSplitPane splitPaneLeft = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
       JSplitPane splitPaneRight = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        splitPaneLeft.setLeftComponent( p1 );
        splitPaneLeft.setRightComponent( p2 );
        splitPaneRight.setLeftComponent( splitPaneLeft );
        splitPaneRight.setRightComponent( p3 );

        JPanel panelSplit = new JPanel();
        panelSplit.add(splitPaneRight);
        cp.add(panelSplit);
       panelSplit.setVisible(true);
       }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"exception occured"+ex);   

     }
   }
     public static void main(String arsg[])
    {

       paneltest frm= new paneltest();
       frm.show ();

       }

       }
       class panel1 extends JPanel
        {
        panel1()
           {
           setLayout(new FlowLayout());
           JLabel l1= new JLabel("panel1");
           add(l1);


           }    

           }

         class panel2 extends JPanel
        { 
         panel2()
           {
           setLayout(new FlowLayout());
           JLabel l1= new JLabel("panel2");
          add(l1);

           }    

         }
      class panel3 extends JPanel
       {
       panel3()
        {
          setLayout(new FlowLayout());
          JLabel l1= new JLabel("panel3");
          add(l1);


         }    

        }
```

Comment: 1) This code starts to charge downhill at `cp.setLayout(null);`  ***Use layouts!*** 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line `cp.setLayout(null)`. This will fix the initial problem.

After that:

- indent the code
- respect Java naming conventions
- don't add panels to the content pane if you add them to the splitpanes right after. A component can be added to a single parent. It doesn't make sense to add them to both
- don't use `setBounds()`. That's the role of the layout manager
- don't extend JPanel and JFrame. Use them
- Respect [Swing's threading policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).
- Don't `catch (Exception)`

Comment: as i removed setLayout(null) and also not adding the panels on container the panels are being displayed but they are not resizable.

Comment: That's because the `panelSplit` panel uses a FlowLayout (by default). Make it use a BorderLayout, and the splitpane will take all the available space in it.